# Simple christmas' wpf styles

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm not sure if such question is eligable, but

I have a wpf (4.0) software for our company and i'd like to make some christmas magic for our stuff via UI of app.

Do you have any simple ideas or already implemented styles for christmas theme?

Comment: Simple way would just you use Visual brushes to overlay images of snow etc in the corners of the window border, Neat idea :)

Comment: Use Adorners to add some snow/xmas stuff :) Have fun !

Comment: thanks! I also think that music is not a good idea. For example, how do you like web sites with music which plays without asking you? :-) If you have a lot of opened sites you will not find the source of music quckly :-)